# Extending WP_List_Table - Error: Call to undefined function convert_to_screen()

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I am trying to extend the WP class WP_List_Table within a plugin.

I am using the code found below. When I excecute my script I get the following message:

> "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function
> convert_to_screen() in
> /home/u794297373/domains/educoder.dk/public_html/lessannoyingcmsforwp/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-list-table.php:149
>
> Stack trace:
>
> #0
> /home/u794297373/domains/educoder.dk/public_html/lessannoyingcmsforwp/wp-content/plugins/lessannoyingcrmforwp/inc/API/Functions/LinkListTableFront.php(23):
> WP_List_Table->__construct(Array)
>
> #1
> /home/u794297373/domains/educoder.dk/public_html/lessannoyingcmsforwp/wp-content/plugins/lessannoyingcrmforwp/inc/Base/SearchContactsFunctionController.php(33):
> Inc\API\Functions\LinkListTableFront->__construct()
>
> #2
> /home/u794297373/domains/educoder.dk/public_html/lessannoyingcmsforwp/wp-content/plugins/lessannoyingcrmforwp/inc/Init.php(33):
> Inc\Base\SearchContactsFunctionController->register()
>
> #3
> /home/u794297373/domains/educoder.dk/public_html/lessannoyingcmsforwp/wp-content/plugins/lessannoyingcrmforwp/lessannoyingcrmforwp.php(55):
> Inc\Init::register_services()
>
> #4
> /home/u794297373/domains/educoder.dk/public_html/lessannoyi in
> /home/u794297373/domains/educoder.dk/public_html/lessannoyingcmsforwp/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-list-table.php
> on line 149"

The line referred to calls the function "convert_to_screen()"

I can't semm to figure out what is going wrong?

The controller code:

```
<?php 
/**
 * @package LessAnnoyingCRMforWP
 */

namespace Inc\API\Functions;

if(!class_exists('WP_List_Table')){
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/screen.php' );
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/class-wp-list-table.php' );
}

 class LinkListTableFront extends \WP_List_Table
 {


   /**
    * Constructor, we override the parent to pass our own arguments
    * We usually focus on three parameters: singular and plural labels, as well as whether the class supports AJAX.
    */
    function __construct() {
       parent::__construct( array(
      'singular'=> 'wp_list_text_link', //Singular label
      'plural' => 'wp_list_test_links', //plural label, also this well be one of the table css class
      'ajax'   => false //We won't support Ajax for this table
      ) );
    }

    /**
     * Add extra markup in the toolbars before or after the list
     * @param string $which, helps you decide if you add the markup after (bottom) or before (top) the list
     */
    function extra_tablenav( $which ) {
       if ( $which == "top" ){
          //The code that goes before the table is here
          echo "Hello, I'm before the table";
       }
       if ( $which == "bottom" ){
          //The code that goes after the table is there
          echo "Hi, I'm after the table";
       }
    }

    /**
     * Define the columns that are going to be used in the table
     * @return array $columns, the array of columns to use with the table
     */
    function get_columns() {
       return $columns = [
          'col_link_id'=>__('ID'),
          'col_link_name'=>__('Name'),
          'col_link_url'=>__('Url'),
          'col_link_description'=>__('Description'),
          'col_link_visible'=>__('Visible')
       ];
    }

    /**
     * Decide which columns to activate the sorting functionality on
     * @return array $sortable, the array of columns that can be sorted by the user
     */
    public function get_sortable_columns() {
       return $sortable = array(
          'col_link_id'=>'link_id',
          'col_link_name'=>'link_name',
          'col_link_visible'=>'link_visible'
       );
    }

    /**
     * Prepare the table with different parameters, pagination, columns and table elements
     */
    function prepare_items() {
       global $wpdb, $_wp_column_headers;
       $screen = get_current_screen();

        /* -- Preparing your query -- */
        $query = "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->links";

        /* -- Ordering parameters -- */
        //Parameters that are going to be used to order the result
        $orderby = !empty($_GET["orderby"]) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["orderby"]) : 'ASC';
        $order = !empty($_GET["order"]) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["order"]) : '';
        if ( ! empty($orderby) & ! empty($order) ) { $query .= ' ORDER BY ' . $orderby . ' ' . $order; }

       /* -- Pagination parameters -- */
            //Number of elements in your table?
            $totalitems = $wpdb->query($query); //return the total number of affected rows
            //How many to display per page?
            $perpage = 5;
            //Which page is this?
            $paged = !empty($_GET["paged"]) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["paged"]) : '';
            //Page Number
            if(empty($paged) || !is_numeric($paged) || $paged<=0 ){ $paged=1; } //How many pages do we have in total?
            $totalpages = ceil($totalitems/$perpage); //adjust the query to take pagination into account
            if(!empty($paged) && !empty($perpage)){ $offset=($paged-1)*$perpage; $query.=' LIMIT '.(int)$offset.','.(int)$perpage; }
            /* -- Register the pagination -- */ 
            $this->set_pagination_args( array(
             "total_items" => $totalitems,
             "total_pages" => $totalpages,
             "per_page" => $perpage,
          ) );
          //The pagination links are automatically built according to those parameters

       /* -- Register the Columns -- */
          $columns = $this->get_columns();
          $_wp_column_headers[$screen->id]=$columns;

       /* -- Fetch the items -- */
          $this->items = $wpdb->get_results($query);
    }

    /**
     * Display the rows of records in the table
     * @return string, echo the markup of the rows
     */
    function display_rows() {

       //Get the records registered in the prepare_items method
       $records = $this->items;

       //Get the columns registered in the get_columns and get_sortable_columns methods
       list( $columns, $hidden ) = $this->get_column_info();

       //Loop for each record
       if(!empty($records)) {
            foreach ( $records as $rec) {

              //Open the line
                echo '< tr id="record_'.$rec->link_id.'">';
              foreach ( $columns as $column_name => $column_display_name ) {

                 //Style attributes for each col
                 $class = "class='$column_name column-$column_name'";
                 $style = "";
                 if ( in_array( $column_name, $hidden ) ) $style = ' style="display:none;"';
                 $attributes = $class . $style;

                 //edit link
                 $editlink  = '/wp-admin/link.php?action=edit&link_id='.(int)$rec->link_id;

                 //Display the cell
                 switch ( $column_name ) {
                    case "col_link_id":  echo '< td '.$attributes.'>'.stripslashes($rec->link_id).'< /td>';   break;
                    case "col_link_name": echo '< td '.$attributes.'>'.stripslashes($rec->link_name).'< /td>'; break;
                    case "col_link_url": echo '< td '.$attributes.'>'.stripslashes($rec->link_url).'< /td>'; break;
                    case "col_link_description": echo '< td '.$attributes.'>'.$rec->link_description.'< /td>'; break;
                    case "col_link_visible": echo '< td '.$attributes.'>'.$rec->link_visible.'< /td>'; break;
                 }
              }

              //Close the line
              echo'< /tr>';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The controller code you posted doesn't call the function, so it's not directly relevant to your problem. The issue seems to be arising from the `lessannoyingcmsforwp` plugin. Is this your own custom plugin or someone else's you're just using?

Comment: It is my own custom plugin. The problem arises when I create an instance of the LinkListTableFront in an other controller by:

  //Prepare Table of elements
  $this->wp_list_table = new LinkListTableFront();  <--- This line sets off the Fatal error.
  $this->wp_list_table->prepare_items();


This is also the case when I try making an instance of the \WP_Link_Table directly.

The problem seems to be calling classes outside my plugin, or using them within my plugin.

Comment: I found that this issue had also been reported in the development of the plugin "Edit-Flow".
They faound the problem to be: "This is because WP_Screen must be available before convert_to_screen() is called. On the front end of the site, Editflow calls the page_to_screen_id() function as part of the WP init action, which takes place prior to WP_Screen being available .

This isn't a problem in admin because the admin_init action includes WP_Screen sooner...

Comment: ... As a temporary workaround, I've updated the conditional inside page_to_screen_id() from if ( function_exists('convert_to_screen') ) to if ( function_exists('convert_to_screen') && class_exists( 'WP_Screen' )) - this works fine for how Editflow is used by our site, but if there are major reasons for having screen adjustments on the front end, it can be addressed by wrapping the functions that call page_to_screen_id() in an action that fires after WP_Screen is included." (https://github.com/Automattic/Edit-Flow/issues/354)

Comment: SOLVED:
The problem was the order of the instanciation. By adding an add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', array( $this, 'initLinkList' ));

The class was called at the correct time.

Comment: You can post an answer to your own question, it's allowed and it'll be more visible than a comment to anyone who reads this in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED: The problem was the order of the instantiation. By adding an add_action( 'call', [ $this, 'initClass' ]); The class was called at the correct time.

Then I had a do_action command on the page where I needed to call the list. Apperently the script was called too early in the initial code.

I ended up with the code:

```
        add_action( 'search_for_contact_or_company', [ $this, 'initSearchList' ] );
        add_action( 'add_contact', [ $this, 'initCreateContact' ] );

    }

    public static function initSearchList( $arg ) {

        $this->search_list_table = new SearchListTableAdmin();

        $searchLess = $arg;

        do_action( 'search_for_contact', $searchLess );

    }
```

The initSearchList function then calls the rendering of the code in my SearchListTableAdmin class.